# How can I give a user the CAP_MKNOD capabillity?

Tags: rsync, devices

Following on from this question: [rsync's relationship with special files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210730/rsyncs-relationship-with-special-files)

In order to back up device files, rsync at the destination needs to be able to call `mknod`.  The usual approach would be to tell rsync to log in as `root` and use the switch `--super`.  (e.g.
`rsync -avz --super ./this root@thatserver:/backup/this`)

I don't particularly want to have rsync processes log in as root.

According to '`man mknod`':

> EPERM (error)
>
> ...and the caller is not privileged (Linux: does not have the CAP_MKNOD
>   capability)...

Is it possible to assign CAP_MKNOD to a user who is not root?  If so, how?

Comment: As an aside, it's interesting that this is a switch that can be supplied to docker containers.

Comment: Do you need it to be per user? You can set capabilities for the executable.

Comment: I'd prefer it to be per-user.  If I add a sticky bit then *every* user can create special files, which isn't very secure either.

Comment: Why do you want to back up device files? Normally you would exclude `/dev` from backups, since it's an in-memory filesystem.

Comment: @Gilles As the previous question explains, the device files are part of a user's backup.  They appear to have been building an OS at the time the backup was taken.  So they aren't really devices that are in use, but they are as far as rsync is concerned, and they just happen to be in the user's folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a capability to a binary file. For example, on the remote copy
`/bin/rsync` to the user's home directory, eg `/home/user/rsync` and make it
executable by them alone, then add the capability:

```
sudo setcap CAP_MKNOD=ep /home/user/rsync
```

When the user runs this rsync on the remote it will be able to create
device nodes.

Comment: And for more interesting reading on CAP_ permissions: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html or `man capabilities`